# Issue on injecting EntityManagerFactory in Websphere with @PersistenceUnit

Tags: websphere, jpa-2.0, code-injection, persistence.xml

I'm having trouble porting a webapp from Glassfish 3.1 to Websphere 8.5.
The problem is the use of JPA2:
the following configuration running in Glassfish does not work in Websphere:

```
<persistence-unit name="pippoPU" transaction-type="JTA">  
<jta-data-source>jdbc/pippo</jta-data-source>
```

and:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "xxxxxxx")
@ViewScoped
public class MioJSFBean implements Serializable {
    .....
    .....

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx = null;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "pippoPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    ....
    ....
}
```

The problem is that the EntityManagerFactory is not injected .. it remains null ..

Both application server are JEE6 compliant.

(a few months ago, I tried on Weblogic 10.3 and, if I remember correctly, I had the same problem when I deployed directly from Eclipse ... It was a known issue that could  be resolved by setting   "Publish as an exploded archive" from the weblogic-eclipse plugin.)

Does anyone have some suggestion?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there's a problem/error with any of the entities in the project.
Websphere only outputs a single line line in the log - I'm sure you'll find it:

```
[ERROR] The server cannot create an EntityManagerFactory factory
```

You need to set the logging level for `com.ibm.ws.jpa.*` to `All messages and traces`. 
Then you'll find the root cause of the problem in the logs.